# Is there a hook that is called only once after plugin bulk update process is completed?

Tags: plugins, notifications

I am trying to send a list of plugin names via email after plugins bulk update.

Using this hook, my function sent various emails, each one with one plugin name because the action is run after each plugin's update:

`add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'inv_update_service_notification_send_function',10, 2);`

This hook is not fired and does not call my function:

`add_action('update_bulk_plugins_complete_actions','inv_update_service_notification_send_function',10,2);`

Is there a hook that is called once the entire plugin bulk update process is completed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the action you're looking for is indeed [`upgrader_process_complete`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/upgrader_process_complete)

The Codex page doesn't say specifically, so I'm not totally certain if it runs for each plugin or after all of them, but it works for me :-)

```
function bgmc_plugins_update_completed( $upgrader_object, $options ) {

    // If an update has taken place and the updated type is plugins and the plugins element exists
    if ( $options['action'] == 'update' && $options['type'] == 'plugin' && isset( $options['plugins'] ) ) {
        // code here
    }
}
add_action( 'upgrader_process_complete', 'bgmc_plugins_update_completed', 10, 2 );
```